# Table outputs correctly until double digits

Tags: javascript, formatting

I asked a similar question yesterday about the format of my table. I ended up changing a lot of my code to try and get this to output correctly but am still having some trouble. I am able to get it to be the correct format when it is outputting the year in single digit numbers, after that the format will not adjust to what I have set. I was also trying to add commas into the numbers on the balance but have had no luck. This is my first time taking a JavaScript class, so I am pretty clueless and the information in my book is not very helpful. Also I have to use console.log() for my output at this point as we have not been taught any other outputs. I will leave my code and some pictures. Any ideas would be great since I am pretty much at a dead end.

```js
function displayWelcome() {
  console.log("Welcome! \nThis program will determine the time to pay off a credit card and the interest paid based on the current balance, the interest rate, and the monthly payments made.")
}

function calculateminimumPaymentment(balance, minimumPaymentRate) {
  return Math.max(20, balance * minimumPaymentRate);
}

function displayPayments(balance, interest, minimumPayment) {

  console.log("Balance on your credit card: $" + balance.toFixed(2))
  console.log("Interest Rate: " + (interest * 100) + "%")
  console.log("Assuming a minimum payment of 2% of the balance ($20 min)")
  console.log("Your minimum payment would be: $" + minimumPayment)
  console.log("\nYear    Balance  Payment Number Interest Paid Minimum Payment")
  var acum = 0;
  var yearcount = 0;
  var paynum = 0;
  var interestPaid = 1;
  var year = 0;


  while (balance > 0) {
    paynum++;
    interestPaid = balance * (interest / 12);
    balance = Math.max(0, balance - (minimumPayment - balance * interest / 12));
    minimumPayment = Math.max(20, balance * minimumPaymentRate);
    acum = (parseFloat(acum) + parseFloat(interestPaid)).toFixed(2);
    var tbl1 = "$" + parseFloat(balance).toFixed(2) + "\t\      " + paynum + " " + "$" + "\t" + parseFloat(interestPaid).toFixed(2) + " " + "$" + "\t\t" + parseFloat(minimumPayment).toFixed(2);
    if (yearcount % 12 === 0) {
      year++
      var tbl2 = "      " + year + " " + tbl1;
    } else {
      var tbl2 = "\t" + tbl1;
    }
    yearcount++;
    console.log(tbl2);



  }
}

var balance = 1500;
var minimumPaymentRate = 0.02;
var interest = 0.18;

displayWelcome()
var minimumPayment = calculateminimumPaymentment(balance, minimumPaymentRate);

displayPayments(balance, interest, minimumPayment);
```

[This is the correct format that is being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dedha.png)

[This is where the output messes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4RXd.png)

[This is what the table is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHHHG.png)

Comment: Have you looked at [String#padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) and [String#padEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Xotic750's comment. Ignore the console output of the snippet and view it in the browser's console.

```js
function displayWelcome() {
  console.log("Welcome!");
  console.log("This program will determine the time to pay off a credit card and the interest paid based on the current balance, the interest rate, and the monthly payments made.");
}

function calculateminimumPaymentment(balance, minimumPaymentRate) {
  return Math.max(20, balance * minimumPaymentRate);
}

function displayPayments(balance, interest, minimumPayment) {

  var pad = 17;
  console.log("Balance on your credit card: $" + balance.toFixed(2));
  console.log("Interest Rate: " + (interest * 100) + "%");
  console.log("Assuming a minimum payment of 2% of the balance ($20 min)");
  console.log("Your minimum payment would be: $" + minimumPayment);
  console.log();
  console.log('Year'.padStart(pad), 'Balance'.padStart(pad), 'Payment Number'.padStart(pad), 'Interest Paid'.padStart(pad), 'Minimum Payment'.padStart(pad));
  var acum = 0;
  var yearcount = 0;
  var paynum = 0;
  var interestPaid = 1;
  var year = 0;


  while (balance > 0) {
    paynum++;
    interestPaid = balance * (interest / 12);
    balance = Math.max(0, balance - (minimumPayment - balance * interest / 12));
    minimumPayment = Math.max(20, balance * minimumPaymentRate);
    acum = (parseFloat(acum) + parseFloat(interestPaid)).toFixed(2);
    if (yearcount % 12 === 0) {
      year++;
      console.log(
        ('' + year).padStart(pad), 
        '$' + parseFloat(balance).toFixed(2).padStart(pad - 1), 
        ('' + paynum).padStart(pad), 
        '$' + parseFloat(interestPaid).toFixed(2).padStart(pad - 1), 
        '$' + parseFloat(minimumPayment).toFixed(2).padStart(pad - 1)
      );
    } else {
      console.log(
        ''.padStart(pad), 
        '$' + parseFloat(balance).toFixed(2).padStart(pad - 1), 
        ('' + paynum).padStart(pad), 
        '$' + parseFloat(interestPaid).toFixed(2).padStart(pad - 1), 
        '$' + parseFloat(minimumPayment).toFixed(2).padStart(pad - 1)
      );
    }
    yearcount++;
  }
}

var balance = 1500;
var minimumPaymentRate = 0.02;
var interest = 0.18;

displayWelcome();
var minimumPayment = calculateminimumPaymentment(balance, minimumPaymentRate);

displayPayments(balance, interest, minimumPayment);
```

Comment: Thank you , I just had to make a few adjustments with the pad and I was able to figure it out!